# JSON google maps array

Tags: php, arrays, maps

please what am I doing wrong when navigating through the array? I need to get latitude using php and json response.
Thank you in advance.

```
$googleurl='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Prague';
$json=file_get_contents($googleurl);
$res=json_encode($json, true);
print $res['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the json not encode.

Try using,

```
$res=json_decode($json, true);
```